# JavaScript: using one text box value as basis for loop to capture values in second text box?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that needs to capture a value (textbox1), and use the value to establish the size of an array. Then i need to use a different textbox (tesxtbox2) to capture the values to populate the array and then process a few calculations.

I can capture the first value fine, size the array, and populate the array IF i use window prompts for the data capture.  I cannot figure out how to replace the prompt method with a text box capture.

Here is the code- and the comments show where I am stuck. In essence, i need to replace the "window.prompt" section with "get element by id" and use the text box, looping thorough the values until the initial number entered (text box1) is fulfilled.

```
            <html>
           <head>
              <meta charset = "utf-8">
              <title>Variance and Standard Deviation</title>

            <style type = "text/css">

            #placement {
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0 0px;
            align:right;
            text-align: left;
            }

            #sorted {
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0 0px;
            float:left;
            text-align: left;
            }

            #mean,{
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0 0px;
            align:right;
            text-align: left;
            } 
            #variance,{
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0 0px;
            align:right;
            text-align: left;
            } 
            #deviation,{
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0 0px;
            position: relative;
            text-align: left;
            } 

            </style>

            <script>

            //declare and intialize variables 
            var capCount = 0; //capture count of variables to be entered
            var count = 0; //parse captured count to an integer
            var arrayTotal=0 ; //total of all values entered into array for math calcs
            var arrayAverage=0; //average (mean) of values in array
            var sortedArray = 0; //array sorted in ascending order
            var values = 0;  //values entered into text box for array population


            function start(formInfo) 
                {
                    var countField = document.getElementById( "count" ); // gets entry from count field on form
                    var capCount = countField.value;    
                    var count = parseInt (capCount);

                    var valueArray = new Array(); // allocate empty array   
                    //start capture and populate array loop
                    for ( var i = 0; i < count; ++i ) //using loops count, prompts user to enter variables until count of loops (count) is reached
                    //STUCK HERE- replace variable capture from window prompt to get value from text box
                    // rather than using window prompt box, need to capture input from the "value" text box,
                    // loop through the text box each time a value is entered and process when the last value (loops equal to count) is entered
                        {
                        var variable = window.prompt("Please enter a value for value " + (i + 1) + "" );  //prompts user to enter a value
                        //var variable = document.getElementById("value");
                        valueArray [ i ] = variable ;
                        } //end capture for loop


                    //calls sort function to sort array into ascending order
                    valueArray.sort ( sort );

                    //calls calcuate function to conduct math and get results
                    calculate ( valueArray );

                }// end build array function



            //sort function
            function sort ( value1, value2 )
            {
                return parseInt ( value1 ) - parseInt( value2 );
            } //end sort

            //calcuate function
            function calculate (theArray)
            {
                //declare variables
                n = 0;
                arrayTotal = 0;
                total_sqr = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; ++i )
                {   
                arrayTotal += +theArray[i];
                n = (n + 1);
                total_sqr += (+theArray[i] * +theArray[i]);
                }
                //mean, variance, deviation calcs
                mean = (arrayTotal / theArray.length); //calcuate mean
                variance = (total_sqr - ((arrayTotal*arrayTotal)/n))/(n - 1);
                deviation = Math.sqrt( variance) ;

                //calls output function to output the resuls of the script
                output( "The sorted order of the values entered is", theArray, document.getElementById( "sorted" ) ); 
                output( "The mean of the values entered is", mean.toFixed(2), document.getElementById( "mean" ) );      
                output( "The variance of the values entered is", variance.toFixed(2), document.getElementById( "variance" ) );  
                output( "The standard deviation of the values entered is", deviation.toFixed(2), document.getElementById( "deviation" ) );

            } //end calculations

            //output function
            function output ( heading, data, results )
            {

                var content = "<p>" + heading + "</p><p>" + data + "</p>" ;
                results.innerHTML = content; // place the table in the output element
            } //end output

            </script>
           </head>
           <body>

           <body>
                <P><h2>This Page calcuates mean, variance and standard deviation</h2></p>
                <form action = "#">
                    <p><label><h3>Enter the # of values to process and click submit:</h3>
                    <input id = "count" type = "number" size = "10"></label>

                <div>
                <input type="button" value="Submit #of values to " onClick="start(this.form);">
                </div>

                <p><label><h3>Enter the x value to process:</h3>
                <input id = "value" type = "number" size = "10"></label>

                <p>
                <input type="button" value="process your values" onClick="process(this.form);">
                </p>


                </form>

           <div id = "sorted"></div> 
           <div id = "placement">
                <div id = "mean"></div>
                <div id = "variance"></div>
                <div id = "deviation"></div>
           </div>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the click of button "process your values" do all the job for you.
On click of "process your values",call the process function,

```
//pseudo code
function process(){
 var length = document.getElementById('count').value
 var value_string = get_the_value_from_second_text_box

 convert value_string to an array(of values you need)

 do_the_computation
 display_the_results
```

}